# Read pdf and find next word after a key word

Tags: python, pdf, full-text-search, apache-tika, pdftotext

I am trying to run the following code in order to search for the next words of a text that come after "examination". 
Input is a pdf that i try to convert to a text using tinka.
Somehow the code throws an error referred to tinka that i do not understand. 
Does anyone know how to fix it or knows another way to implement my problem?

```
import re
from tika import parser

raw = parser.from_file('application0001.pdf')
print(raw['content'])

list_of_words = raw.split()
search="examination"
next_word = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(search) + 1]
print(next_word)
```

This is the error I get when running it and I do not get what it means.

```
2019-05-24 09:53:53,217 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Retrieving http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.19/tika-server-1.19.jar to /var/folders/xn/p33pzhs179n33z55z66lqcn00000gn/T/tika-server.jar.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 716, in getRemoteJar
    urlretrieve(urlOrPath, destPath)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mauritius/Desktop/text_search.py", line 7, in <module>
    raw = parser.from_file('application0001.pdf')
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tika/parser.py", line 36, in from_file
    jsonOutput = parse1('all', filename, serverEndpoint, headers=headers, config_path=config_path)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 328, in parse1
    headers, verbose, tikaServerJar, config_path=config_path, rawResponse=rawResponse)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 522, in callServer
    serverEndpoint = checkTikaServer(scheme, serverHost, port, tikaServerJar, classpath, config_path)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 571, in checkTikaServer
    getRemoteJar(tikaServerJar, jarPath)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 726, in getRemoteJar
    urlretrieve(urlOrPath, destPath) 
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
[Finished in 2.7s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Mauritius/Desktop/text_search.py"]
[dir: /Users/Mauritius/Desktop]
[path: /Users/Mauritius/miniconda3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/Mauritius/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin://anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin]
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like the download of the Apache Tika jar is failing. Do you have working internet where you are running it? Does maven work normally otherwise?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i never used maven so i do not even know how to check if it is running. Internet works fine with best glass fibre.

Comment: Your stacktrace shows the jar it is trying to download, does that work for you outside of Python?